# How to convert XML SOAP response to php string

Tags: php, soap

One of my clients created a web service on SOAP:

```
    POST /TiendaOnLine.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: tiendawow.webvillanet.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tiendawow.webvillanet.com/ObtenerExistencia"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ObtenerExistencia xmlns="http://tiendawow.webvillanet.com/">
      <articulo>string</articulo>
      <usuario>string</usuario>
      <password>string</password>
    </ObtenerExistencia>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then I created a php file to consume the web service:

```
    <?php
            $url="http://tiendawow.webvillanet.com/TiendaOnLine.asmx?WSDL";
            $parameters=array();
            $parameters['articulo']="code";
            $parameters['usuario']="user";
$parameters['password']="pass";        
            $client = new SoapClient($url,$parameters);
            $result = $client->ObtenerExistencia($parameters);
            var_dump($result);
    ?>
```

And I get an output like this:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["ObtenerExistenciaResult"]=> string(5) "11.00" }
```

What I need is to be able to save only the 11.00 (or whatever the value is depending on the articulo) on to a variable for later use, like saving it on a database. ¿How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the property `ObtenerExistenciaResult` in the `$result` object.

```
if(property_exists($result, 'ObtenerExistenciaResult')) {
    $value = $result->ObtenerExistenciaResult;
}
```

`$value` will now contain the string `11.00` if the property exists.

You should have some logic in there to handle errors and making sure the data that is coming back is what you expect. But this will get you the value of that property assuming it exists.

[PHP Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

[property_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot slapyo, this was exactly what I needed.